# Seed Data From Realm Sync Configuration in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, realm, realm-object-server

So, here's my issue:

The local path for realms on iOS are located in the Documents Directory. I can open them with:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

Opening a sync realm is different as they are located by URLs
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realms

I have a UICollectionView with a `Results<Object>` I can render default data to called in the AppDelegate from a separate file by writing to the Realm on launch

Separate File

```
class SetUpData {

// MARK: - Seed Realm

static func defaults() {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    guard realm.isEmpty else { return }

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(List.self())
        }
    }
}
```

App Delegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     // MARK: - Set Up Realm If Deleted

    var config = Realm.Configuration()
    config.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true

    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    SetUpData.defaults()

    return true
}
```

From here, client-side (iOS), I am able to successfully log in (rolled my own log in but the values correspond to the Realm Object Server (ROS) admin user) and retrieve the default values from `List.cell` and begin writing "Lists" to my application.

However, when I configure my realm with a `Sync Configuration` par **opening a synchronized Realm requires a User that’s been authenticated to the Object Server and that’s authorized to open that Realm**, I reasonably crash in my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` `return lists.count` **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** because there is no initial data to return.

That makes sense. But what do I do?

Do I need to create a Realm file in the default config and migrate it to the server? I attempted to change my config to a Sync object in the App Delegate with the code below (which is what I am using in `ListViewController`). No dice.

```
private func setUpRealm() {

    let username = "\(LoginViewController().username.text!)"
    let password = "\(LoginViewController().password.text!)"

    SyncUser.logIn(with: SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: username, password: password, register: true), server: URL(string: "http://000.000.000.000:9080")!) { (user, error) in

        guard let user = user else {
            fatalError(String(describing: error))
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let configuration = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: URL(string: "realm://000.000.000.000:9080/~/realmList")!))

                    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
                    self.lists = realm.objects(List.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "created", ascending: false)
                    self.notificationToken = self.lists.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in

                        guard (self?.collectionView) != nil else { return }

                        switch changes {
                        case .initial:
                            self?.collectionView.reloadData()
                            break

                        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                            self?.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                                self?.collectionView.insertItems(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}))
                                self?.collectionView.deleteItems(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}))
                                self?.collectionView.reloadItems(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}))
                            }, completion: nil)
                            break

                        case .error(let error):
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm does not provide an API to convert a standalone Realm to a synced Realm currently. If my understanding is correct, it is necessary to copy the data from the seed Realm to synced Realm when opening the synced Realm.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks!